# CUDA 9.1 installation error: does not have a version.txt file! Ensure you are installing to an existing toolkit directory

Tags: linux, installation, cuda

I'm installing the run file version of CUDA 9.1 on a linux box which has CUDA 8.0 on it.

The file I'm installing is: `cuda_9.1.85.1_linux.run`

```
sudo cuda_9.1.85.1_linux.run
```

The download options were: `Linux / x86_64 / Ubuntu / 16.04 (linux mint) / runfile (local) / Base Installer`

The error I get is:

```
Installation directory '/usr/local/cuda-9.1' does not have a version.txt file! 
Ensure you are installing to an existing toolkit directory.
```

This perplexes me because CUDA 9 is not installed, the whole point of running the installer is to install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here is that you need to first install the CUDA 9.1 package which I found in my distribution's package manager. Then, second, this installation, the CUDA 9.1 toolkit, is installed on top of that. There is a patch to install on top of the toolkit. Lastly, you will need to install cuDNN if you're installing this for deep learning.

Comment: Have same problem. Running Ubuntu. Can't find the package in my package manager. Where is it? What do I do?

Comment: [follow instructions here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads)

Comment: Yeah, it needs to be downloaded from Nvidia and installed

Answer (score 5):

**You might be trying to install the "patch" instead of the main installer.**

---

Is your file about 70 MB size instead of the more expected 1.7 GB size? If yes, then you are probably installing the "patch" first before the main installer.

I also tried installing the "patch" first and got an error and then I was confused. Then I realized I had the wrong filename and did an `ls -alrth` and got the filename for the larger 1.7 GB installer and tried that and now it is installing without the error message.

The files I downloaded were not clearly labeled to indicate what file was the installer and what was the main installer (the filenames are all cuda_${version}.run).

Answer (score -1):

@Trevor Boyd Smith is correct
u need to install "cuda_9.0.176_384.81_linux.run" first
Then run these patches in order
cuda_9.0.176.1_linux.run
cuda_9.0.176.2_linux.run
cuda_9.0.176.3_linux.run
cuda_9.0.176.4_linux.run